# Trouble executing ssh IPAddressA -l user "ssh -l IPAddressB ls" from my bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I'm currently facing a weird problem while executing a command from my bash script.

My script has this command,

```
ssh IPAddressA -l root "ssh -l root IPAddressB ls"
```

where IPAddressA & IPAddressB  would be replaced by hard coded IP addresses of two machines accessible from each other.

The user would enter the password whenever asked. But, I'm getting this error after I enter the IPAddressA's password.

```
root@IPAddressA's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the inner ssh password is prompted, there's no interactive keyboard available. You can get what you want with ssh tunneling.

```
ssh root@IPAddressA -L2222:IPAddressB:22 -Nf
ssh root@localhost -p2222
```

The first line open a tunnel, so your localhost `2222` port points to `IPAddressB:22` andd bring the ssh process in background (`-f`) without executing a command (`-N`)
The second line connects `IPAddressB:22` through the new opened tunnel

Answer (score 2):

There's a better trick for that..

In ~/.ssh/config add a host entry for IPAddressA, configured like so:

```
Host IPAddressA
    User someguy
    ProxyCommand ssh -q someguy@IPAddressB nc -q0 %h 22
```

The slick thing about this method is that you can scp/sftp to IPAddressB without any weird stuff on your shell command line.

For bonus points, generate yourself a public key-pair and drop the public key on both IPAddressA and IPAddressB in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. If you don't put a password on it, you won't even be bothered to enter that.

Additionally, if you're trying to get access to a remote LAN that only has a single entry point - SSH can actually act as a VPN client, bridging you through the proxy host. Of course, the remote end needs to support tap/tun devices (as does your local machine)... But if it's all there already.. super painless mechanism to bridge.